# Solution for a harmonic oscillator driven by a sweeping frequency

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Given a [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Sinusoidal_driving_force) driven by a sweeping frequency:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + 2\zeta\omega_0\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \omega_0^2 x = \frac{1}{m} F_0 \sin\left(\omega(t) t\right), $$ 
with $\omega(t)=x_{Trianlge}(t)+\omega_t$. $x_{Trianlge}(t)$ being the [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave). $\omega_t$ doesn't need to be resonance frequency $\omega_0$, but we know that $\omega_0$ lies in the range of the sweep.

Can this be solved analytically?

Comment: What about solving it piecewise and trying to stitch the pieces? Or decomposing the triangle wave into harmonics, solving for those and then summing the solutions?

Comment: @mvw i guess your first mehod should work

Comment: @mvw hmm the result for a piece doesn't look very promising, according to [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ei2575aan4p)...

Comment: @draks The solutions are unwieldy (integral forms that require numerical solution) but what is wrong with them?